# Binding RDLC Report to DataSet DataTable with multiple FillBy Methods

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datatable, rdlc

I am currently working in a **RDLC report-generating application**, and one of the reports is bound to a `DataTable` in my `DataSet`, which has multiple `FillBy` methods, which are needed depending on some criteria the user has already chosen. My problem is, one of the `FillBy` methods is generating additional columns that I need in my report, but they don't appear through the available columns to populate controls in the report. I can only choose between the columns available from the default `FillBy` method of the `DataTable`.

Is there any way of choosing which `FillBy` method is used in the `DataSet` when I want to set the source of my report's controls? I would like not to change the default `FillBy` method since it is already needed in other parts of my application.

P.S. If there is any code needed, table structure etc just tell me and I will reply as soon as possible. Also, either `VB.NET` or `C#` is accepted, since I can easily translate between these two.

Comment: *"one of the `FillBy` methods is generating additional columns*".  Then you it wrong.  Each table adapter is associated with a `DataTable` and that `DataTable` has specific colums.  **EVERY** query in that table adapter is supposed to produce the same set of columns to match the `DataTable` schema.  If you need a different set of columns then you need a different `DataTable` and table adapter.

Comment: This is a pretty straight-forward way of doing it, can't believe I didn't think about it. I guess I still have to practice since I haven't really worked with bound projects so far. Thank you very much!